# Swipe to Refresh hides before loading the WebView

Tags: android, webview, swipe-gesture

I implemented swipe to refresh for my WebView and its working fine. But there is one problem which i am not able to solve. The problem is my Swipe to Refresh hides after 6 seconds. It did not remain there till the loading for WebView is completed. What i want is that Swipe to refresh should remain visible till the page fully loads.

**My Implementations**

```
swipeView = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
myWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://m.facebook.com");
swipeView.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener()    
        {
        @Override
         public void onRefresh() 
         {
                     swipeView.setRefreshing(true);
                   ( new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() 
                           {
                             @Override
                             public void run() 
                               {
                                swipeView.setRefreshing(false);
                                myWebView.loadUrl("http://m.facebook.com");
                               }
                         }, 6000);
                   }});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use WebView listener and finish your Swipe in the onPageFinished listener..

For example like below

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // do your stuff here

      swipeView.setRefreshing(false);
    }
});
```

For your case, change your code like below,

```
swipeView = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe);
myWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // do your stuff here

      swipeView.setRefreshing(false);
    }
});
swipeView.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener()    
        {
        @Override
         public void onRefresh() 
         {
               myWebView.loadUrl("http://m.facebook.com");

         }});
```

Comment: That is a handler time which you used.

Comment: Yeah i know that, but what should i do with it? Should i delete it after implementing onPageFinished?

Comment: The delay (in milliseconds) until the Runnable will be executed. Remove this Runnable and use King Of Masses onPageFinished listener

Comment: nice to hear that @Faiyaz . Happy to help :)